# Procedural Terrain generation is upside down in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
import blocks
import random

class World:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tile_list = []
        TILESIZE = 20
        minStoneHeight = 1
        maxStoneHeight = 8
        x = 0
        y = 0
        height = 10
        width = 100


        for x in range(width):
            minHeight = height - 1
            maxHeight = height + 2
            height = random.randrange(minHeight, maxHeight)
            minStoneSpawnDistance = height - minStoneHeight
            maxStoneSpawnDistance = height - maxStoneHeight
            totalStoneSpawnDistance = random.randrange(minStoneHeight, maxStoneHeight)
            for y in range(height):
                if y < totalStoneSpawnDistance:
                    t = blocks.stoneBlock(x*20, y*20 + 100)
                    self.tile_list.append(t)
                else:
                    t = blocks.dirtBlock(x*20, y*20 + 100)
                    self.tile_list.append(t)
            if(totalStoneSpawnDistance == height):
                t = blocks.stoneBlock(x*20, y*20 + 100)
                self.tile_list.append(t)
            else:
                self.tile_list.append(t)
                t = blocks.stoneBlock(x*20, y*20+100)



    def draw(self, screen):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            tile.draw(screen)
```

This is the code I use for procedural terrain generation in pygame. I adapted it from a script in C# for Unity. The issue is that pygames grid orgin is in the topleft and unitys is at bottom left. I was wondering how I would get my terrain to not be upside down?

Comment: Pygame naturally takes a long time to load images. You could try using a smaller image type (jpg, jpeg) which would take less time to load.

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

It s a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You maust move the player in the application loop rather than the event loop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                currentPlayerImg = playerImgBack
                playerYSpeed = -5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerYSpeed = 0

    #<--| INDENTATION
    
    playerX += playerXSpeed
    playerY += playerYSpeed

    screen.blit(bgImg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(currentPlayerImg, (playerX, playerY))
    pygame.display.update()
```